# Gravity moving ball

Tags: java, applet

The following program is simple and is supposed to draw a ball that falls down to the effect of gravity and then bounces back up. The program seems to compile but I keep getting an exception error.

In the class ball, the fonction move contains the physics formula to calculate the velocity and displacement.

package gravity;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Ball extends StartingPoint{
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public int x;
public int y;

private static final double dt = .2;
private static final double g = 9.8;
public double vy = 0;

Ball(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void move(){
    vy += g*dt;
    y += (1/2)*g * dt*dt + vy * dt;
    if (y >= (this.getHeight() - 20 -1)){
    y = this.getHeight() - 20 -1;
    vy = -vy;}

    }


public void paintBALL(Graphics g){
g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
}
}
```

---

```
package gravity;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class StartingPoint extends Applet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int x = 400, y = 25;
    Ball ball;

    //private static final int nbBalls = 1;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(800, 600);

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        Ball ball = new Ball(x,y);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new RunBall(ball));
        thread.start();

    }

    public class RunBall implements Runnable{
        private Ball ball;
        RunBall(Ball ball){
            this.ball = ball;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){

                ball.move();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(17);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                repaint();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        ball.paintBALL(g);
    }

}
```

---

the compiler keeps adding the following exeption :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gravity.StartingPoint.paint(StartingPoint.java:61)
at java.awt.Container.update(Container.java:1835)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:267)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:233)
at apple.awt.ComponentModel.handleEvent(ComponentModel.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4852)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `start` method, you've re declared `Ball`...

```
    Ball ball = new Ball(x,y);
```

This means that the instance field `ball` is still `null` when `paint` is called.

Instead, in your `start` method, initialise the instance field...

```
ball = new Ball(x,y);
```

`Applet` is very out of date and you should be prepared for a lot of flickering as the applet is repainted.

If you can, I'd recommend using a `JApplet` but using a `JPanel` as the primary paint surface. By overriding the `JPanel`s `paintComponent` method, you get double buffering support by default, which will stop the flickering without you doing any additional work, just don't forget to call `super.paintComponent` before y do any custom painting...

Answer (score 0):

`paint` is called before your Ball is defined, simply change your paint:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  if(ball != null)    
    ball.paintBALL(g);
}
```